# Gaming, collision on view

Tags: android, view

I am designing an archer game. When the arrow hits the target it stops moving. What I am trying to accomplish is to define a formula to predict/get location where the target and the arrow meet on the view.

The problem arises when the arrow got a speed varying on initial velocity and the arrow also have angles. Plus, the images on screen are placed by `x - bitmapt.getWidth/2` (same for height, h/2..)

If an arrow moves too fast then I need to calculate an error so the arrow does not miss the target even though they are supposed to be on same x and y as we have that, the arrow moves as `X + speed` pixels. So I came to something like this!

```
if(arrow[i].getX() + v0x[i] / 2 >= target.getTarget().getX() && arrow[i].getX() <= target.getTarget().getX() + v0x[i] / 2)
```

I use the velocity of x/2 to specify the error margin.

```
arrowX + velocity/2 >= collision point >= targetX + velocity/2
```

However, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure mathematical problem, and there are much literature when it comes to collision detection. I propose that you use a library. For 2D I recommend [JBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/). It is a physics engine (used for example in Angry Birds). You get collision detection and much much more :)

Comment: I have sorted my problem, thanks for trying to help at least :D